# Debian - ssh Does Not Run On Boot

Tags: debian, ssh

I'm finding this by using the command `systemctl status ssh`, and I get a report of (dead). My networking seems to be fine as `ping 8.8.8.8` gets responses. Somewhere online I saw a similar problem where it was suggested to try `grep sshd /var/log/auth.log`. The logs for today are as follows:

```
Jan 25 20:28:48 RTIBUSDock sudo:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh start
Jan 25 20:28:49 RTIBUSDock sshd[580]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
Jan 25 20:28:49 RTIBUSDock sshd[580]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
Jan 25 20:28:49 RTIBUSDock sshd[580]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
Jan 25 20:49:23 RTIBUSDock sshd[1255]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 25 20:49:23 RTIBUSDock sshd[1255]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 25 20:54:20 RTIBUSDock sudo:     root : TTY=ttySAC2 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl enable ssh
Jan 25 20:54:30 RTIBUSDock sshd[1255]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jan 25 20:56:04 RTIBUSDock sudo:     root : TTY=ttySAC2 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl enable ssh.socket
Jan 25 21:00:52 RTIBUSDock sshd[1020]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 25 21:00:52 RTIBUSDock sshd[1020]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 25 21:01:08 RTIBUSDock sshd[1020]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jan 25 21:58:01 RTIBUSDock sshd[826]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 25 21:58:01 RTIBUSDock sshd[826]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

This all started happening after moving the boot volume (on an SD card) from one computer to another.

Comment: Possible firewall problem...

Comment: Very good idea, thank you. I'll try running it on another network and report back. I forgot to mention that when I `sudo service ssh start` it comes off without a hitch. Does that mean anything about firewalls?

Comment: When moving from one computer to another you may also encounter issues that arise from devices not coming up or not becoming ready when they once did. Or the drivers are getting switched when the service is looking to use a device and it appears busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using `apt-get purge openssh-server && apt-get install openssh-server`.